# What is the best way to query stake pools by ticker?

Tags: stake-pool, staking, cardano-graphql, query

As a developer, I'd like to have a service that retrieves the information of a stake pool based on its ticker (or all the stake pools with that ticker, I know there can be duplicates).

I'm thinking that with `graphql` I need to query first the list of `stakePools` (which is huge) and then filter that by ticker, which is inside the `metadata` of the pool.

Is there a way to do this in a more performing way or a service already solving this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of stake pools should only be a couple of thousand which is tiny in comparison to number of blocks or even worse the number of transactions.

It can be done with a relatively simple SQL query on the database maintained by `cardano-db-sync`.

Comment: Is it possible to query the ticker of a pool directly from the db? Or should I have to get first the URL of the metadata? I understand that the ticker is not a field in the stake pools database. Am I right? Thank you.

Comment: The ticker is stored in the db. You want the `ticker_name` field of the `pool_offline_data` table,